# How to print string by awk in special format?

Tags: awk, sed, printf

it's that able to convert following string

```
3.840527449999989,6A3,06,67,07,DF,0D,63,81,AA
4.306243875,601,02,3E,80,00,00,00,00,00
```

to format string like below

```
3.840527449999989,6A3,06 67 07 DF 0D 63 81 AA
4.306243875000000,601,02 3E 80 00 00 00 00 00
```

Note that:

- timestamps should postfix 0 if necessary
- data bytes should remove , between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '{$1=sprintf("%.15f",$1); for(i=1;i<3;i++) sub(OFS,FS)} 1' file
3.840527449999989,6A3,06 67 07 DF 0D 63 81 AA
4.306243875000000,601,02 3E 80 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: great, it avoid sed problem "sed more than one number or 'g' in substitute flags", but still to see 8 or 9 postfixed, not 0

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what `still to see 8 or 9 postfixed, not 0` means.

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf`:

```
awk -F, '{printf("%.15f,%s,%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)}' file
```

Output:

```
3.840527449999989,6A3,06 67 07 DF 0D 63 81 AA
4.306243875000000,601,02 3E 80 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: Updated the answer.  Thanks, @karakfa!

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$1=sprintf("%.15f",$1)}1' file | sed 's/,/ /3g'

3.840527449999989,6A3,06 67 07 DF 0D 63 81 AA
4.306243875000000,601,02 3E 80 00 00 00 00 00
```

`sed` (gnu) is to replace `,` with spaces, to do that in `awk` you have to specify all the fields with delimiters in place (e.g. not set `OFS` and `print $1 "," $2 "," $3,$4,$5` etc).

Comment: it's strange to found that posfix number is not 0, but 9, my macos output second line with awk section like :
4.3062438749999998,601,02,3E,80,00,00,00,00,00

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/^[0-9.]\{17\},/!s/,/0,/;ta;s/,/ /3g' file
```

If the first field is not length 17 insert a `0` until it is, then replace the third `,` onwards with a space.

N.B. pre-supposes that the first field is not longer than 17 and that this field is number of the type shown. Also that the record layout is as the example and field two does not contain a `,` i.e. is not a quoted field.

Comment: sed is also power full, never use 'a;' before, great!